# Array form element validation in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to validate form array element below but getting error. I wonder if it is set as an array because other normal elements are being validated without a problem.

Thanks in advance

**ERROR**

```
TypeError: document.formABC.textQualificationSet is undefined
```

**JS**

```
var textQualSubject = document.formABC.textQualificationSet[0]["Qual Subject"].value;

    if(textQualSubject == ""){
        alert("ERROR: Please enter at least first Qualification Subject");
        return false;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="textQualificationSet[0][Qual Subject]" value="" />
```

Comment: Have you looked at a validation library? http://parsleyjs.org/documentation.html Your users and any developer looking at this after you will thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing it wrong it, must be like this

```
document.getElementsByName('textQualificationSet[0][Qual Subject]')[0].value;
```

**Reference**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName